# How is a StaticValueProvider different from a constant?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

According to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#runtime-parameters-and-the-valueprovider-interface):

> StaticValueProvider allows you to provide a static value to your pipeline. The value is available during pipeline construction, so you can use the value to change your pipeline's workflow graph.
>
> Use StaticValueProvider when you know the value ahead of time. See the StaticValueProvider section for examples.

That sounds just like a constant though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that it functions as a constant, but is a separate type so that it can be passed as a `ValueProvider<>` type for functions/interfaces that require this.